# Run application.commandbars() outside excel or word

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, ms-word

i'm trying to figure out a way to run a simple line of vba code like:

```
application.commandbars("research").enabled = false
```

without opening excel or word (i would like to ref this line of code both for excel and word)

i was thinking of creating a word / excel object in vbs but couldn't think of a way to use this line of code in the same context of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get an existing instance of the application in vbscript code like so:

```
Dim excelObj 
Set excelObj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

You can then call any application methods on that object:

```
excelObj.CommandBars("research").Enabled = False
```

For Word, do the same as above but use "Word.Application".

Note: [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will throw an error if no instance of the application is currently running. In that case use [CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5(v=vs.90).aspx) instead, with the same parameters.

Comment: works like a charm just a small note: if you run into the error "ActiveX component can't create object: 'GetObject'" you should pass GetObject() with an empty string GetObject("","Excel.Application") see here : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4e45e0de-a480-4301-a618-a480175a44b9/microsoft-vbscript-runtime-error-activex-component-cant-create-object-getobject?forum=ITCG